# SQL Query Subtract 1 month

Tags: sql, dateadd

I need to query SQL for data that falls into a last month date.  I thought I was using the correct query logic but I get no results and I know there are results.  The snippet of code is this:

```
MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE) = DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE())
```

This is giving me no results and I need to get anyone who has a join date of last month.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your full query?

Comment: Also some sample data would be nice.

Comment: `MONTH()` returns a month number. `DATEADD()` returns a date.  A month is never going to be equal to a date.

Comment: Do you mean within the last month meaning e.g. today is 6/20 so 5/20 to 6/20 or last month 5/1 to 5/31.  And do you have time components or is it just a DATE?

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE()))
```

You need to compare apples with apples, so compare the numerical month on both sides of the equation.

Massive credit to @PaulL for figuring this out before I did.

**Update:**

As @DasBlinkenLight and Matt pointed out, just comparing by month leaves the door open for multiple years to be returned.  One possible fix would be to also compare the years, e.g.

```
WHERE MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE())) AND
      YEAR(n.JOIN_DATE) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: If more than 1 year is present in the dataset this would return results from multiple years.  If you also add AND YEAR(n.JOIN_DATE) = YEAR(DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) that will solve that issue.

Answer (score 2):

`MONTH(...)` produces a month number. You should not compare it to the result returned by `DATEADD`, which is actually a date.

If you are looking for everyone who has joined less than a month ago, you can do it like this:

```
WHERE DATEADD(month, 1, n.JOIN_DATE) > GETDATE()
```

This takes into account the year and the day as well, not only the month.

If you are looking for everyone who joined last month, no matter on what day, you can use a more complex condition:

```
WHERE MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) = MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE)
  AND YEAR (DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) = YEAR (n.JOIN_DATE)
```

The second condition is necessary to avoid confusion between members joining last month and members joining on the same month one or more years ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE) returns a numeric which indicate the month in date m.JOIN_DATE
DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE()) returns a date which indicate date in last month.
So, you can use this instead :
MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE)= MONTH(DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE()))
OR
n.JOIN_DATE = DATEADD(month, - 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: you will need a between or greater than less than to get all of his results not just the one day

Comment: Also this will not work if there is a time component on his columns

Answer (score 1):

`MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE)` will only return the numerical value of the month (e.g.: `11` or `5`).

`DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())` will simply subtract one month from the current date.  It is still in a `DATETIME` format.

You may be looking for:

```
MONTH(n.JOIN_DATE) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())),MONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())),1) AS StartOfLastMonth
    ,DATEADD(day,-1,(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1))) AS EndOfLastMonthAsDate
    ,DATEADD(day,-3,CAST(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1) AS DATETIME)) AS EndOfLastMonthMidngith
    ,CAST(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS OneMonthAgoStrartOfDay
    ,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS StartOfToday
    ,DATEADD(MS,-3,CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)) AS MidnightLastNight
```

Okay As people have definitely illustrated there are a lot of different answers to your question and all are built upon similar premise. using `DATEADD()` with a negative number to go back a month.  Or to compare month and year to see if they are the same.  The former being geared at 1 month ago to today and the later being last month.

All of the answers so far, expect @DasBlinkenLight and @TimBiegeleisen, fail to take into account `TIME` component of your column and the `GETDATE()` function if you have one.  If your column is `DATETIME` you will need to take that into account.  The above `SELECT` query that will arm you with some ways of getting to different dates that i suspect will meet your needs.

As far as using `BETWEEN` with dates be careful! because the values you put in are inclusive so if you put `GETDATE()` on the right side of the between statement you will get today's results too but you might really want UP TO to today in which case you should change your right side argument. Also I am not sure about Oracle, mysql, etc. but Micrsofot SQL-Server is accurate to `.003` milliseconds. So if you really want to look at midnight of a date you should look at `23:59:59.997` because .998 and .999 will round up to the next day.

Also to further simplify if you don't want time components you can also cast your column to `DATE` and it essentially drops off the time and the `BETWEEN` because a little clearer too, e.g. `CAST(n.JOIN_DATE AS DATE)`

There are definitely other questions on this subject on stackoverflow I encourage you to research.

Answer (score -1):

I knew this was a simple one and I was missing something to it.  My code was wrong based upon the many responses I received on this and I was comparing apples to oranges and not apples to apples. Once I added the `Month()` around the `dateadd` function, it worked.

Comment: Beware of when your data contains multiple years.  If you want all of last month you need to compare both the YEAR of last month to the YEAR of your n.JOIN_DATE and the month.  Otherwise if your data has multiple years you will get that month for every year in your results

Answer (score -2):

The reply to this answer are correct. But in the light of best practice writing your query this way will make it less SARGABLE, hence making it ignore indexes if you have one. It might be better to write it as

```
WHERE n.JOIN_DATE between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)  AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
```

based on the comment below I have modified the query. I guess I did not read the question in depth.

Comment: If I ran that today, 2016-06-20, it would not return 2016-05-02, which it should,  but would return 2016-06-03, which it shouldn't.  Downvoted accordingly.

Comment: Go back to your earlier version DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE().  That one returned the correct date range of 5/20 to 6/20.  This one returns 6/1 to 5/31 23:59:59.000 which is both in the wrong order and not the correct dates.  I don't know what @DanBracuk was typing to get his results

Comment: The question said he wanted sometime that falls in last month which is the 5/20 range I presume or did I misinterpret that?

Comment: I am not sure if the OP is 5/1 to 5/31 or 5/20 to 6/20.  But if the latter your original SQL statement was correct I am not sure what the other users comment is saying because your code was correct except that it would include a time component that likely should be stripped off